# How to update or remove Font Awesome from Gantry 4 - (rocketheme Myridd Template)

Tags: css, joomla, fonts

I'm new - and will try to keep it short.

Issue
- I can't find any files or instructions on how to remove or update the font awesome files.

I have tried:
1. developer tools to find the correct files - no luck;
2. Joomla template file manager - no luck
3. RT Forum - no relevant answer / no subscription
4. this forum and the Google - no useful results;

Install type
Recently updated Joomla 3+ install with latest Gantry 4 and Myriad template from Rocket Theme(RT).

font awesome 4 installed with RT template

Why the question
I'm currently using font awesome 4 and want to sponsor the kick start project / get more icons. It is pointless without being able to make these changes - and I need to pay a bunch for RT support.

what I need
If possible I would appreciate someone directing me to:
- how to find these specific files; and 
- how I might change/update them; or
- what tool i can use to locate the files necessary; and 
- a little guidance on what I'm looking for.
- any recommendations on using font awesome in future - for example: is it better to use Font Awesome CDN?

Thank You I appreciate your(s) time and effort.
Jas

Answer (score 1):

I believe Gantry 4 handles the FontAwesome icons through the LESS files in the Gantry library.  Try digging around in **/libraries/gantry/assets/jui/**.

I am already backing the kickstarter and recommend the CDN method.  In some projects, I have added the FontAwesome CDN code in the template index.php right before the closing head tag to get some of the newer icons in the 4.x series.